# Enqueue calls in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, queue

For an enqueue function, I want to add a value to an array(the queue) however I keep getting a cast error. Anyone know how to fix it?

```
arr[tail] = o;
tail = (tail + 1) % arr.Length;
```

The error is pointing to the first line.

The declared variable:

```
private int tail = 0;
public int[] arr = new int[10];
```

also, `o` is from the method....

```
Enqueue(object o){ }
```

The error I am getting is CS0266

Comment: What is `o`? What is `arr`? What is `tail`?

Comment: also, what does the error say?

Comment: private int tail = 0;
public int[] arr = new int[10];

also, o is from the method.... Enqueue(object o){

Comment: The error is CS0266 - cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists.

Answer (score 0):

your array is of type `int` not `object`. hence you cannot simply do this:

```
arr[tail] = o;
```

when `o` is of type `object`.

change this:

```
Enqueue(object o){...}
```

to this:

```
Enqueue(int o){...}
```